# Adjust the left container as per right container height without using height property in css

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, joomla

I have two divs one left side and another right side . In right side contents are dynamically loaded by click the left side menus. Based on the contents height the left side container also increase by same height. i  attached screenshot for this problem

[image]

Expected result be:

[image]

![enter image description here][3]

Any help be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this as follows, basically we are using position relative and playing with it

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/99ZJT/1/show/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="container2">
    <div id="container1">
        <div id="col1">
            <!-- Column one start -->

        </div>
        <div id="col2">
            <!-- Column two start -->

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container2 {
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#ffa7a7; /* column 2 background colour */
}
#container1 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    right:50%;
    background:#fff689; /* column 1 background colour */
}
#col1 {
    float:left;
    width:46%;
    position:relative;
    left:52%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#col2 {
    float:left;
    width:46%;
    position:relative;
    left:56%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[**Original Article**](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks)

Comment: Nice to hear that Sudhar other answers are helpful as well but this is well tested by author and have better browser compatibility Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/VLLmW/1/)**

**CSS:**

```
.columnwrapper {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 5px;
}
#contentliquid, #leftcolumnwrap {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-spacing: 5px;
}
#leftcolumnwrap {
    width: 15%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="columnwrapper">
    <div id="leftcolumnwrap">
        <p>This is the left column. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="contentliquid">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

by using display:table for parent div

and use display:table-cell for child div

html

```
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child1">
            Adjust the left container as per right container height without using height property in css
        </div>
        <div class="child2">

    aka
        </div>

</div>
```

css

```
.parent{display:table}
.child1{display:table-cell; float:left;width:45%; border:1px solid #ccc}
.child2{display:table-cell; border:1px solid #ccc;vertical-align: top;}
```